# sqlquery in R does not return all rows from query

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, odbc

I am executing below commands in R:

```
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=serveripaddress;database=DBName;uid=sa;pwd=pwd;')

FactActivity <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, "SELECT DimCourseID,DimPatientID FROM DWH.FactActivity", as.is=TRUE)

nrow(FactActivity)
```

In my database I have total **238634** rows but in R I am getting total rows = **237652**.

This is happening for all tables (I tried it for three tables).

Any idea what am I missing which is reducing no of rows in my resultset in R?

Comment: ? `nrow(FactActivity)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, couldn't solve it, eventually switched to using RJDBC with a Java driver to get around it.

Comment: Yes it did. Would recommend this approach, since it also doesn't depend on local resources of the operating systems - it is portable across platforms (assuming you have access to a Java installation).