# Rows with missing values in R when copy data from SQL Server

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, rodbc

I am using the library `RODBC` to connect R and SQL Server. I am loading a table from SQL Server to R. In SQL Server, I do not have any rows where column `ApplicationID` is `NULL`. But in R I get data `dataSQL` with some missing `ApplicationID`. Not sure if I need to try different library or just use `RODBC` with proper settings.

I tried to save data from SQL Server to CSV and read it in R. But that creates extra column with no name. I think since some values in SQL Server large than it scans for.

```
library('RODBC')

# connect to SQL
cn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};server=TRGVSQL3100;database=GroupData;trusted_connection=yes;")

# Load dev data
Sys.time()
dataSQL <- sqlQuery(cn, "select * from [DATAStage].[dbo].[Table_Name]")

Sys.time()
on.exit(odbcClose(cn))
```

Comment: Your question is a bit vague and lacking in detail, but off the top of my head, perhaps the `ApplicationID` is empty string for some records.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This is the point. ApplicationID is numeric and does not have any Null's in SQL server. I never came across this type of problem before.

Comment: What happens when you run the above query directly in SSMS?  Do you also see `NULL` values there?  Do you even see the same number of records?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Yes I get the same rows and columns numbers. in SSMS i dont have any NULLs

Comment: Then my guess is that something is going on here with your R code or your use of the R API.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I use R studio.

Comment: How are you checking for NULL? Only looking at the top of thousands or millions of rows? Run a count query in MSSQL: `SELECT Count(*) FROM mytable WHERE ApplicationID IS NULL` and check in R: `sum(is.na(dataSQL$ApplicationID))`.

Comment: @Parfait SELECT Count(*) FROM mytable WHERE ApplicationID IS NULL gives results 0 and in R  sum(is.na(dataSQL$ApplicationID)) 72

Comment: I switched to library(odbc) library(DBI) and i dont see any missing anymore

Comment: The only idea I can think is the ID number exceeds R's integer limit of 32-bit. What is the data type of this ID field in SQL Server? Can you localize where missings are in R -at end or beginning? Please post few matching rows of SQL Server non-NULLs and R with NAs.

Comment: @Parfait in R i see all NA'a for all columns for 72 rows. In SQL table ApplicationID is integer (with not null option). So it is hard to determine what is getting na's in R.

Comment: How many digits are in those non-NULL IDs in SQL Server? R has a limit it can hold.

Comment: @Parfait up to 9

Comment: I found another question about this library from @Radhi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43200384/sqlquery-in-r-does-not-return-all-rows-from-query

Comment: What happens if you convert to decimal: `select ApplicationID*1.0 As AppID, * from [DATAStage].[dbo].[Table_Name]` OR `select convert(Decimal(12,0), ApplicationID) As AppID, * from [DATAStage].[dbo].[Table_Name]`?

Comment: @Parfait did not help it. I can try to update all R libraries to make sure I have all up to date. But in odbc i dont have any problem.